# How to run a particular test in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest

I have 60 functional tests in one file. I wrote them in Notepad++ and used py.test as the test framework. Today I decided to swap Notepad++ with PyCharm. I opened my file of functional tests in PyCharm and ran the tests from PyCharm, as you can see in the picture:

[image]

Now, after confirming that I could run all of the tests, I tried to run an individual test, for example `test_login_with_extantUser_using_email`. Logically, I right-clicked on the test, expecting a "run test" button or something similar to appear. But no such thing appeared. In fact, it appears that there is no way to run an individual test by simply right-clicking on it.

So my question is, how can I run an individual test? Must I set up a *configuration* for each one in the Edit Configurations menu? That would take a very long time, considering that I have 60 tests.

[image]

Comment: do you try this ? => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36079152/run-a-specific-unit-test-function-inside-pycharm-ide-5-0-4

Comment: For what its worth try deleting the configuration and then try again.

Comment: hey guys, i am randomly trying different things. Somehow I managed to get a class of tests, rather than all of the tests, to run. I don't know what I did. I will try to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem. It's a bug in Pycharm that needs to be fixed. I will explain the bug.

Right-clicking an individual test will not display the option to run the test if the test is not a member of a class that inherits from unittest.TestCase. This is true even if you are not using unittest, as in my case, in which I am using py.test.

When I made my py.test test classes inherit from unittest.TestCase, I got the option to run tests individually when I right-clicked on a test.

I have reported the bug to Pycharm. Time will tell if they fix it.
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-26754

Answer (score 0):

Base on pt.test [doc](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#calling-pytest-through-python-m-pytest) you can specify particular test_case for running with -k (which means keywords obviously). In your case it should be like `pytest -k "test_login_with_extantUser_using_email"` if you running in CLI.

If you want to run particular test with Pycharm, you have to fill 'Keywords' field in Run/Debug Configurations.
[image]

Best Regards.